# Change the selection of ComboBoxCell in one row based on same ComboxCell in another row

Tags: combobox, grid, gxt

I have a grid with inline editing in which I have a ComboxCell, say it contains value 1,2,3,4,5. I want to have a feature such that when the user selects 2 in one row, any other row for which the selected value is 2 changes it's selection to the former row's previous values.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this by adding ComboBox editor to the column.

```
combo.addBeforeSelectionHandler(new BeforeSelectionHandler<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void onBeforeSelection(BeforeSelectionEvent<Integer> event) {

            Integer item= event.getItem();
            ColumnConfig<Sample, Integer> column= columnModel.getColumn(1);
            ComboBox<Integer> box= (ComboBox<Integer>)event.getSource();
            String text= box.getSelectedText();
            Collection<Store<Sample>.Record> records= ivGrid.getStore().getModifiedRecords();
            if(records.isEmpty())
            {
                Sample sample= getSampleByIndex(item);

                if(sample!=null)
                {
                    Record record = listStore.getRecord(sample);
                    record.addChange(sampleValueProvider.index(), Integer.parseInt(text));
                }
                else 
                {
                    Sample sample2= listStore.get(item-1);
                    if(sample2!=null)
                    {
                        Record record = listStore.getRecord(sample2);
                        record.addChange(sampleValueProvider.index(), Integer.parseInt(text));
                    }
                }
                return;
            }

            for(Record r : records)
            {
                Sample currentSample= (Sample) r.getModel();
                Change<Sample, Integer> displayOrder= r.getChange(sampleValueProvider.index());
                if(displayOrder==null)
                    continue;
                if(displayOrder.getValue()==item)
                {
                    Record record = listStore.getRecord(currentSample);
                    record.addChange(sampleValueProvider.index(), Integer.parseInt(text));
                }
            }

            ivGrid.getView().refresh(true);

        }
```